# Update query does not recognize the fields of the table it is run on

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have a table named *history* with fields:

id, accessionNumber, date_borrowed, date_returned, fine

I intend to update the table's row in the following manner when the query is run:

1- insert today's date into return_date

2- subtract the borrow_date from return_date(=today's date), multiply by a constant that I am going to send as a parameter and insert the result into fine

I have been looking around for hours now, but as I'm a beginner I couldn't get much out of it.

This is my query that doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

```
UPDATE history
SET date_returned = CURDATE() ,
fine=DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),STR_TO_DATE(history.date_borrowed, '%m/%d/%Y')) * @some_constant
WHERE id = @id and accessionNumber=@accessionNumber
```

I am using MySQL Workbench 6 and C# if that's is going to help.

The error message I am getting is :

> Incorrect datetime value: '2013-12-11' for function str_to_date

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: What are the column names?  In the beginning of your post you mention fields with names **date_returned**, and **date_borrowed** but then later in your post you refer to columns named **borrow_date** and **return_date** !  Which is it?

Comment: sorry for the typo, the field name is date_borrowed, now corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess that `borrow_date` is really stored as a `date` and not as a string.  If so, then the query can be simplified to:

```
UPDATE history
    SET date_returned = CURDATE() ,
        fine = DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), borrow_date) * some_constant
    WHERE id = @id and accessionNumber=@accessionNumber;
```

Comment: the field IS of type date, and thanks a lot it is working now.